# GIT C/C++ Library as DLL

Tags: c++, c, windows, git, dll

I was wondering if anyone can recommend JGit like library but is instead written in C/C++. Essentially what we need, is dll file that we can bundle with our application to initialise repo and do daily pulls from repo.

Answer (score 5):

It took me 3 seconds of googling to come up with: [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I asked for recommendations :) There is one by Tortoise too, but I'm sort more interested in experience.

Comment: @nirth, Tortoise has a GPL license so you would be required to release your source code.  libgit2 is GPL with a linking exception, so you would not be required to release the source.

Comment: Good point, I did not have time to check licences yet. Thanks

Comment: @nirth: Checking licenses should always be the first thing you do. If the license is incompatible with what you want to do, then that's the single argument that should prevent you from using it without breaking the law.

Comment: I have to say, libgit2 does not support remote repositories. No push/pull operations supported. I guess. Other libraries seem to have other limitations, which leaves either installing git silently via Installer or using JGit and installing JRE

Comment: @DavidSergey I don't know what you mean. I googled libgit2 and here is some refference to remote servers https://libgit2.org/docs/guides/authentication/

Comment: @TomášRůžička check the date on my comment. November 9th of 2011 :) They added a lot of features in last 10 years :)

Comment: @DavidSergey :-D oh, sorry :-D